# problem with array following curve modifier

Tags: modifiers

I want to model a Mobius strip, so I modelled a cube and deleted its two faces firstly. Secondly, I created a NURBS circle and modelled it as a Mobius shape.

After arraying the cube, I used the curve modifier, however, I found that the cube transform into a unexpected shape.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vakrb.png)
[image]

[image]

Comment: the curve modifier does modify the object. This is normal/expected behaviour. If you want to minimize it, use more subdivision and/or bigger angles on your curve. If you provide your blend file, we could answer more specific to your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris! Because it's my first time to use this website so I don't know how to upload my file. I am trying to solve this and upload my file......

Comment: just open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: Dear Chris, thanks! It works! [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Q4qVq0Vb" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Q4qVq0Vb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change twist method on your curve to Z-Up:

[image]

Comment: It really helps me! Thank you very much Chris ^ ^!

Comment: glad i could help. you are welcome!